# Concept problem in exterior algebra and wedge product

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, exterior-algebra

We know for multicovectors wedge product hs the bilinearity property:

$(aw + a' w')\wedge \eta = a(w\wedge \eta)+ a'(w'\wedge \eta)$

The problem is: does here need $w,w'$ to be the same grad i.e. both of them are k-covectors?

When we talk about exterior algebra ,we construct $\Lambda\left(V^{*}\right)=\bigoplus_{k=0}^{n} \Lambda^{k}\left(V^{*}\right)$ then what is the meaning of the sum here? And why they are disjoint?

Comment: It's just a formal direct sum, and in that direct sum the associative law holds for any elements, whether or not homogeneous.

Comment: Why they disjoint and what's the meaning of the sum for elements in it?

Comment: The elements of $\bigwedge V$ are tuples $(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ where $a_i\in\bigwedge^i V$. What does that mean? It means we can treat $\bigwedge V$ as an algebra.

Comment: Oh you use external direct sum,the wedge product on $\wedge V$ is elementwise?